# How to run projects when xampp and project folders are in two different computers?

Tags: xampp

I want to place and run my project from the second computer when xampp is installed on first computer, is it possible to map between xampp and my project which are present in two different pc's. If it is possible how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can do that. After a lot of research I got it. If we want to access the project from any other external path(shared network) rather than our PC general location where xampp is located, do the following.

1) Connect to a shared network by mapping the path in your PC [connecting to a shared folder](http://etc.usf.edu/techease/win/files-sharing/how-do-i-connect-to-a-shared-folder-on-the-network/)
If you are using windows7 go to file explorer and check "Map Network Drive" on the top.

2) After that go to xampp control panel-> apache-> config-> search for "c:/xampp/htdocs"(where you are accessing your previous project) -> now change it to the new path where your project currently hosted/placed(shared network/any other folder).

3) stop the sevices and restart the xampp that's it you can now access your project folder which is located in different folder/server.